# Review audit failure... and no, I don't understand

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I failed a review audit. And I don't understand why. It's not link-only, because the answer would stand on it's own without the link. It's not spam, the link is actually on topic. As the whole answer, it's not exactly great, but it's reasonably on topic.

It was deleted as spam or offensive and I can see nothing offensive about it either.

So what did I miss?

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14283364

Comment: Look at the link url.  A typical spammer trick is to copy legit content but then hide the spam url in an innocent looking link.  If the post looks too good to be flagged then you'll want to look a bit closer.  Also a good way to survive an audit.

Comment: I mouse-overed the URL at the point of the review and it looked legit. When I failed it, I actually **clicked** it and went to the site and it indeed was a tutorial site about linking in VS. Yes, it had ads... but how am I too know how many ads are too much on an external site?

Comment: @HansPassant I posted the link to the failed audit, so you can see the actual link.

Comment: It's possible that this user posted a bunch of answers, all linking to that site. In that case, the answers are spam. Of course, this information is missing when reviewing a single post via the queue.

Comment: The original content [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37719951/17034).  Somebody noticed, yay, you can't win them all.

Comment: OK, thanks, with all the additional info it does make sense. I think it's a bad audit though because you don't get that info with the review :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The context that you didn't have was that this same user had posted that same link to an ad-supported blog across six answers in rapid-fire succession. This was the only one with any content in it, and the others were just of the form

> Check out this will help you: [link]

A moderator spam-flagged all of them to put a temporary posting block on that location.

However, if you go to the question, you'll see the content of that answer is plagiarized from the accepted answer above it, with only slight tweaks. The original:

> By default, the binary version of OpenCV-3.x doesn't contain the separate libs like opencv_core.lib. Instead, these modules are integrated in opencv_world.lib, so you only need to link to it.

this answer:

> Yes, OpenCV-3.x doesn't contain the separate libs. Instead, these modules are integrated into opencv_world310.lib and opencv_world310d.lib so you only need to link to it with VS.

It was clearly copied from the accepted answer in an attempt to insert the link to their ad-backed blog.

All that said, I can see how neither the wording nor the link taken out of context would make it obvious that this is spam, so I've cleared the spam flag on this one answer (but left it deleted). That will remove it as an audit case.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a "behind-the-scenes" bit, this was probably picked up by Smoke Detector (a bot that monitors SO for potentially bad things) as ending with a link, and probably flagged by a moderator (only has -1, which typically means a mod spam flagged).

As Hans noted, this is a common tactic of spammers, to post something that sounds legit, only to have a spam link at the end. I don't blame whomever spam flagged it, because I tend to err on the side of spam if the poster would benefit from the link. If you hang around SD long enough, you'll see why for yourself (there's 3 or 4 of these a day on average).

Even if it weren't spam, however, it doesn't really answer the question, It's a comment with a link, which means it likely would have been flagged as Low Quality and deleted there (which is what I would have done). Without the link, that answer is useless. So it still could have wound up as an audit.

If you're ever in doubt, though, click the link to the question itself and look. It's not the first questionable audit and it won't be the last.

Comment: *this was probably picked up by Smoke Detector* in this case it wasn't. There's no record of it in MetaSmoke, but answers ending with a link are usually detected by the bot (and reviewed by humans).