# VLQ review failed. No, I don't understand

Tags: feature-request, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15862141

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This post has severe quality issues. **It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.** Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.

Sorry, I do not understand. A mod deleted this. It seems to be an answer. Was it good or not? I don't know and don't care. That's what **voting** is for. Yes, it does have links, but they seem to be on topic and even if the links were deleted, that answer would still have value. So it's not "link-only".

Was it part of a spam attempt for the tutorial link? Surely we don't have mods deleting stuff because a single link contains ads? Which tutorial doesn't?

I'm sure the mod was correct in deleting it, but I don't see any way to see why this was deleted **from the context given in the VLQ review queue**.

Can we please stop with the audits that can only be passed if we have more information than available in the context given in the audit? [It's not the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337843/review-audit-failure-and-no-i-dont-understand).

---

Screenshot on request:

[image]

Comment: This looks very surprising, and probably this questions the moderator's trust. There definitely should be a comment for reason (since there's no negative votes), although this post looks wrong (Go doesn't require runtime).

Comment: I'd like to recommend you to modify the title so it attracts more people: "Answer deleted without a proper reason"

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi How about changing the title to  "Do you even know why this answer was deleted by a moderator, what happened next will blow your mind"?

Comment: @BhargavRao the title exactly describes what the problem is, and this is not any kind of title spam. Review audits are known for their inaccuracy, and it results in less interests.

Comment: Yep, the original title is perfect. My comment was just a reply to your recommendation to have a more attractive title.

Comment: Have you checked (at least hover over the link, without clicking it) where the links are leading to? Might be an ok-ish answer to spam for their own site.

Comment: @Tom I hovered both links to make sure they weren't complete BS. After failing the audit I actually clicked them and they lead *exactly* where I would have guessed they would according to the URL.

Comment: A spam flag got his attention, (the second link seems low quality too) - but I also think he deleted it because it didn't look like an answer was in it (and there isn't, aside from "install Go".) The answerer has no reputation to help give them benefit of doubt. I think I get why it was deleted.

Comment: @AaronHall I don't disagree with the mods decision to delete it. But from *the context it was given as an audit* I don't see why I should have voted to delete it. VLQ is for quality problems. I do not see any here. One of the links leads to a tutorial and that has ads. If it were a spammer adding this link to many posts, I agree it's spam. But one single link? I don't vote to delete because a single link has ads on top of content. I would have to vote to delete the entire internet. My point is **context**. The mod had context, that was not given to me on the audit. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: It was flagged as spam, but I should have cleared the spam flag instead of accepting it so it wouldn't end up as an audit. Sorry.

Comment: Related: [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647)

Comment: @nvoigt "The mod had context, that was not given to me on the audit. That defeats the purpose." - That's why you can click through to the actual context. Then if you disagree with the resolution, you can always skip it, and (after reviewing relevant precedence) you should bring it up on meta. As an audit item goes, I agree that it wasn't very fair, but that's a system issue.

Comment: @Braiam wow that's turtle-slow reaction from SE.

Comment: "Can we please stop with the audits that can only be passed if we have more information than available in the context given in the audit?" That would mean removing all audits. So... yes I am for this.

Comment: "Clearing" the spam flag means that it wouldn't have been an audit, but doesn't that also mean that it wouldn't be input for the spam filter? That doesn't seem like a desirable outcome either.

Comment: @TylerH You don't need any outside context to pass this audit.  The outside context would affect what type of flag you'd use, but not *that* the post merits flagging.

Comment: "stop with the audits that can only be passed if we have more information than available" IIRC, audit questions are chosen without human intervention. Failing a single audit is not really a bad thing, despite being frustrating. It just means you disagree with the close reason, or missed something the closer(s) saw. It's failing it too often that is the problem...

Comment: @TylerH - *"That would mean removing all audits. So... yes I am for this"* - And what would you propose as an alternative (better) solution for the problem of robo-reviewers?

Comment: @StephenC a broad overhaul of the current system, including bringing on another 5 or 6 moderators. The issue is that the current audit system is not actually auditing anything, it's just placing landmines dressed up as bad questions as "gotcha" attempts. It's like police entrapment.

Comment: @StephenC What would be better is a more intelligent system that checks for a few things, like how frequently you review, in reference to your rep and your other site actions, whether your review choice is different from everyone else's, etc., where suspect reviews would be auto-flagged and sent to the moderator team for \*gasp\* *actual auditing*

Comment: Umm ... and how is that practical?  I can't see half a dozen more moderators sticking their hands up.  And one person's "intelligent system" is another person's "fascist algorithm".  What we have is obviously not perfect, but seriously.  Nobody is forcing you to do reviews.  And what is the worst that will happen if you occasionally fail a flawed audit?

Comment: The answer looks sufficiently low quality to me (not to mention that the question should be closed for a complete lack of details). It says to install Go and provides some tutorial links. It's a pretty low quality, practically link-only answer to a very low quality question.

Comment: Seriously.  Have all the mods spend five minutes looking at potential audit candidates.  They can tear through a hundred, possibly many more, in that time, rejecting bad ones and accepting good ones.  Only use these for audits for the next six months.  Rinse and repeat twice a year.

Comment: If that one was spam, then isn't [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21961842/103167) too?  (Seems to be the only other link to the same blog, but maybe the moderators have been cleaning them up by the hundreds, where search can no longer find them?)

Comment: @ben If that one was spam, then I wish someone would clean up the `Android` tag... I often think I belong to the lowest quality tag on this site (yes, I agree they are spam)

Comment: @StephenC Nobody is forcing us to do reviews but if no one does reviews then the system falls apart and things don't get closed or reopened or approved or deleted, etc. etc. Also, pay attention to the elections and you'll see there are *always* more candidates than positions. Stack Overflow has no shortage of skilled potential moderators who are also interested in being one. The problem is that the system is picking questions and injecting them into the process, and a nontrivial amount of these questions are *bad* picks. There are many solutions of varying comprehensiveness. Even Will's works.

Comment: I am going to ask again, as I have never had an answer in several years. *Why are reviewers expected to identify spam?* It doesn't have anything to to with VLQ, close-votes, reopen votes, ... It is a completely orthogonal function. And then expecting them to identify spam *as part of an audit* only piles misconception on misconception. Please could somebody at SO get their thinking cap on and get these manifest absurdities addressed.